# Laravel - error within my web routes for inbox

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an inbox but I am having difficulty understanding my routes (I am new to laravel so please excuse if this is a silly mistake). Basically I can view the inbox web-page as per the below screenshot if I type '/inbox' after 'learninghub.org/admin'  [image]

However from my navigation menu when I click the link to the 'inbox' page, a blank page loads and my url, obviously reflecting my web.php is incorrect. Does anyone know how I could fix this so it routes to the correct page?[image]

Web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//Routes for users&courses. Applied middleware defining what users can access these routes by using a can method which was set using a gate facade. 
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware('can:user_management')->group(function(){
        Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
        Route::resource('/courses', 'CoursesController', ['except' => ['show']]);
        Route::resource('/permissions', 'PermissionsController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    });
    //Within the admin prefix a second middleware has been applied to change the role of user which can access the below routes. 
    Route::middleware('can:calendar_management')->group(function(){
        Route::get('events', 'EventsController@index')->name('events.index');
        Route::post('/addEvents', 'EventsController@addEvent')->name('events.add');

    });

    Route::view('inbox', 'admin.inbox.index', [
        'data' => App\Inbox::all()
   ]);

   Route::get('inbox/create', 'InboxesController@create')->name('inbox.create');
   Route::get('inbox/index', 'InboxesController@showInbox')->name('inbox.index');
   Route::get('inbox/outbox', 'InboxesController@showOutbox')->name('index.outbox');

});
```

app.blade.php which contains the nav bar link

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route ('admin.inbox.index') }}">
      Inbox
 </a>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the **view route** to inbox.index, like so:

`Route::view('inbox', 'admin.inbox.index', [
        'data' => App\Inbox::all()
   ])->name('inbox.index');`

And remove the route `Route::get('inbox/index', 'InboxesController@showInbox')->name('inbox.index')`.

---

The difference between clicking the menu and going through the url is because the url is going to the **view route** and the menu is going to the **get** route.